# Reassignent to val results in assigning the reference (Spark Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to update the value of centroids by reassigning it as shown in the figure. The expected output was an array of array of doubles. But instead it seems to assign the reference object. What is causing this behavior and how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with reassignment and there is nothing wrong with your array.
You just shouldn't depend on arrays to be pretty printed as they are meant to be Java primitives, it's a REPL feature that isn't reliable: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/3711#issuecomment-292384823

You can still print the contents with something like:

```scala
val centroids: Array[Array[Double]] = ???

centroids.map(_.mkString(" ")) foreach println
```

Comment: In addition, RDDs are immutable, so there shouldn't be an issue in your code with mutating references.